# Converting string to date and get date string

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

In my app I have a string 'date'="2015-03-16".

I need to show it in a label as Lunes 16 de marzo 2015 (Monday 16 March 2015). I am using the following code to do it:

```
   NSString *dateStr = date;

    // Convertimos el string date a objeto de fecha
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-d"];
    NSDate *fecha = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"DATE CONVERTIDO A FECHA =%@", fecha);

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"];


    fecha = [df dateFromString: date];

    NSLog(@"date: %@", fecha);
```

But at the end I get (null) for the variable 'fecha'
Log --> `date: (null)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the `DATE CONVERTIDO A FECHA` log statement was fine?

Comment: setDateFormat determines how NSDateFormatter will PARSE the string. It needs to match the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in opposite direction after your `df` formatter replace your code with this:

```
NSString *dateStr=@"2015-03-16";
// Convertimos el string date a objeto de fecha
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *fecha = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"DATE CONVERTIDO A FECHA =%@", fecha);

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"];


NSString *newDatestr = [df stringFromDate:fecha];

NSLog(@"date: %@", newDatestr);
```

Hope it helps...........:)

Answer (score 1):

You were using format `@"yyyy-MM-d"`, Use `@"yyyy-MM-dd"`

```
NSString *dateStr = date;

// Convertimos el string date a objeto de fecha
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];//You were using only d
dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle
NSDate *fecha = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"DATE CONVERTIDO A FECHA =%@", fecha);

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *newDatestr = [df stringFromDate:fecha];
NSLog(@"date: %@", newDatestr);
```

Comment: Thank you,  I have changed my code as you propose, but the log is the same --> date: (null)

Answer (score 1):

Your `df` formatter code is doing another `dateFromString` And I think you intended to go the other direction for this second formatter (e.g. `stringFromDate` of the `fecha` previously determined).

Comment: Thank you Rob. I have also the answer from Ayan Khan, in the same direction like yours.